# Error when CodePush (Cordova) meta tag is included

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meta, code-push

I have the next error showed in Chrome console :

**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https://codepush.azurewebsites.net 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-gpnLwpFw97DB28/JjA3G79AHgq5DtCgFiFwjahrA1d4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

Its happen when add this line to de index.html file :

```
***<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://codepush.azurewebsites.net 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />***
```

Answer (score 1):

Change meta tag to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://codepush.azurewebsites.net 'self' data: gap: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http: wss: ws:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * filesystem: cdvfile: data:; media-src * blob:">
```

has fixed this issue for me.